# "me [gerund]" or "my [gerund]" at the beginning of sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

> A.1 The lions reacted to **my** singing.
>
> A.2 The lions reacted to **me** singing.
>
> B.1 **My** singing alarmed the lions.
>
> B.2 **Me** singing alarmed the lions.

As far as I know, both A.1 and A.2 are grammatical: "me" and "my" are interchangeable, although there is a little difference in meaning.

Can we say the same refering to B.1 and B.2? Why does B.2 seem ungrammatical? If it is, what grammatical rule, if any, impedes using "me" in B.2?

Answer (score 8):

*My singing* is a noun, and will always be grammatical; it's what the lions reacted to in A1, and it's the subject of the sentence in B1.

In A2, the lions reacted to **me**, who was singing. *Singing* here is effectively an adjective describing *me*. *Me* is the correct form in this position in the sentence.

In B2, the subject of the sentence is **Me*. That's not right; it should be *I*: "I, singing, alarmed the lions". It's really awkward; if you do need that sort of construction it would be better phrased as "Singing, I alarmed the lions" or "I alarmed the lions with my singing."

As Barry has said, *me* is sometimes heard as a dialectal replacement for *my* ("I'll get me coat"), in which case it turns B2 into B1. If this is the case, *me* is unstressed and pronounced /mɪ/ rather than /mi:/.

Comment: I wonder about this. Can't it be argued that the subject of the sentence is not the speaker, but the whole of the non-finite clause _me singing_? After all, wouldn’t we say ‘Me singing is a very different thing from me dancing’?

Comment: @BarrieEngland We might say that, but it's a colloquial shorthand, I think. Spoken grammar is an odd beast!

Comment: This answer isn't correct :( The Original Poster asked about gerunds. If *singing* is a gerund then (1) doesn't a noun. It could easily involve a clause here. The same is true for the other three sentences too. Also *my singing* isn't a noun, although admittedly it does have one in it.

Comment: In A2 it's extremely doubtful that *singing* is being used as a modifier of *me*. This would definitely seem to be a clause. In B2 the subject of the sentence is not *me*, but *me singing*. B2 is completely grammatical if *singing* is a gerund. There's nothing wrong with the sentence at all (the observation about there being a dialectical reading's accurate but by the by).

Comment: @Araucaria I suggest you write an answer, then.

Comment: The reason I'm commenting Andrew is because other posts are getting closed and linked to this. Barrie's comment above is quite correct. I don't think I'm going to get enough time to write a good answer for this for learners right now. It would have to be very long to cover the necessary ground. Also it's quite difficult to answer, because you'd need to make sure you were being very accurate in order to not accidentally mislead learners.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't advisable, because some might think you’re using *me* instead of *my* as a determiner. That may be possible in some dialects, but it isn’t in Standard English.

Comment: +1 It suggests the Stage Irishman or 'Walking Gentleman'.